# Spring JPA: Should the Save() method commit data to the database?

Tags: java, spring, repository, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using `Spring data` for my project, I am using a Standard `Repository` that `extends CRUD Repository`.

My code is working as expected, however when I call `repository.save()` the database is **not** altered?

Do I also need to then call a `commit` after this in order to alter the Database? Or should the `repository.save()` method be altering the database automatically?

Comment: Typically the save method should be wrapped inside a transaction (spring-data does this transparently for you). If you write your own methods you need to annotate your modifying method with `@Transactional`.

Comment: I have annotated the main method that I am calling save with with a transactional annotation but still not working

Comment: Could you post the code of your repository including the save method + the TransactionManager configuration?

Comment: how can I find transaction manager? This is my first spring project, thanks

Comment: Hmm.. i suggest to start with the getting-started guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: Please tell me whether you're finally able to commit data from `JpaRepository.save()`. I am facing similar issue (listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679766/jparepository-save-method-does-not-commit-using-derby-db)).
Can you have a look at it and help with resolve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When your application runs, the Entity Manager associated with the thread keeps control of modified or added objects, the save() method just do this, it's a mark that says: "this should be saved in the database".

The database DML (insert,update,delete) is not sent to the database while you save things, it's done at the end just before commit, it's delayed to the last moment.

It's possible the send the DML to the database anytime you like using the Entity Manager's flush() method, in fact you can debug the database log and see your queries going through, but this changes to the database will only be visible within your DB connection until the commit is issued; commit() is a method of the transaction associated to the Entity Manager.

In some frameworks like play 1.4.x the commits is issued after the response view is correctly parsed and rendered.